# Type is assignable to the constraint of type 'Type', but 'Type' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Type'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

There are a few questions already asked like this. But I think this a little more specific.

Please see this example:

```js
interface Body {
  legs: number;
}

interface Kingdom {
  animalia: {
    sound: string; // meow..
    body: Body;
  };
}

function GetBody<
  Category extends keyof Kingdom,
  B extends Kingdom[Category]["body"]
>(cat: Category): B {
  // stuff..
  return { legs: 4 }; // <==== Error!
}

// called like: GetBody('animalia').legs
```

The Error says:

```
Type '{ legs: number; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
  '{ legs: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'B', 
  but 'B' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Body'.ts(2322)
```

What am I doing it wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Consider that your code allows this: `GetBody<keyof Kingdom, Body & { eyes: 2 }>('animalia')`. To fix, don't introduce a second generic, just replace the return type with the constraint of `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `B extends Kingdom[Category]["body"]` **does not** mean that `B` is `Kingdom[Category]["body"]`, instead it means that `B` must be **assignable** to `Kingdom[Category]["body"]`.

So, as @Aluan pointed out, a **type** like `{legs: number, eyes: 2}` is perfectly valid for `B`. `{legs: number, eyes: 2}` **does extend** `Kingdom[Category]["body"]`.
This means that `{ legs: 4 }`, the object you return, couldn't be enough. It would be perfect if `B` were exactly `Kingdom[Category]["body"]`, but this is not always the case.

In your situation, there is no need for a generic. Indeed, it's wrong to use one because you need exactly `Kingdom[Category]["body"]`:

```js
function GetBody<
  Category extends keyof Kingdom,
>(cat: Category): Kingdom[Category]["body"] {
  return { legs: 4 };
}
```

**Note**: there is already a TS interface called `Body`. Change the name of yours.