# Return type in generic typescript function not understood by typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I write the `listToList` function below, so that:

- both `listItem` and the return type can only be a `string` or `undefined`, nothing else
- if `listItem` is `undefined`, return `undefined`
- if `listItem` is a `string`, return (a different) `string`

In this case, I have two lists, and sometimes I have an item from one list, and I want to get the item with the same index from the other list. But the `listItem` might be `undefined`, in which case I want the method to return `undefined`.

```
function listToList<T extends string | undefined>(listItem: T, startList: string[], endList: string[]): T {
  if (listItem === undefined) {
    return listItem; // returning undefined here gives the same error as below
  }
  const index = startList.indexOf(listItem); // no error here, TypeScript knows that listItem must be a string
  if (index === -1) {
    throw `Item not in list!`;
  }
  return endList[index]; // <-- error!
}
```

The error is

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | undefined'.
```

But it can't be anything else than a string here, since I've checked for `undefined`! And typescript knows this, since it doesn't complain when I call `.indexOf(listItem)` a few lines before.

Why doesn't type guarding work here, what am I doing wrong, how can this be written instead?

Edit: [here](https://playcode.io/1156850)'s a Javascript version of the code, that works. The problem is the Typescript-part.

Comment: Why do you need a generic type? Why not simply use (listItem: string | undefined, statList: string[], endList: string[]): string | undefined ?

Comment: @Simon because in that case, if I send in a `string`, it comes out as `string | undefined`, which breaks other stuff. The function is used in several places, sometimes the listItem is guaranteed to be a `string`, sometimes not. Also, I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: "Why doesn't type guarding work" and "how can this be written instead" are 2 separate but related questions; which one is *primary* (i.e., the one which an answer needs to address in order to be acceptable)? If it's "why", then the issue is that the type system is unable to model the higher order equivalence `arr[arr.indexOf(x)]===x`; there's no way for `arr.indexOf()` to return a number *and* narrow `arr` so that the prop at the returned index is known to be `T` (which may be narrower than `string`).  I can go into more detail if I write up an answer, but only if that's the primary question.

Comment: @jcalz "How can this be written instead" is the primary question. Preferably including reasons how/why it works and why this doesn't, so the information can be used for other similar cases. That would definitely be an accepted answer. I already got an answer below, but I haven't accepted it yet, because I feel like there must be a better/more correct way to do it.

Comment: @jcalz That would be a completely different function. I don't want to return `listItem`, I want to return the value with the same index from the second (different) list. T is always primitive. I only return `listItem` in case it's `undefined` (line 3), because Typescript doesn't let me to just return `undefined`.

Comment: To be more clear, in my case I have two lists with languages and locales. So, by sending in `"Español"` as `listItem`, it should return `"es-ES"`. By changing the place of the lists, it should do the same conversion in reverse.

Comment: @jcalz I made a javascript version of this, that works exactly like it should on [playcode](https://playcode.io/1156850). I just can't get the Typescript types to work.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now, I didn't realize that `endList`'s item was being returned ‍♂️.  Let me erase some of my comments and reply again; the issue is that string literal types exist, `T` might be *narrower* than `string`, and so it's quite likely that the return value will not be of the right type.  As shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKpkyw).

Comment: ... So you don't actually want to return `T` and probably the best approach is overloads , since the alternative is conditional typing like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJA95m) which the compiler doesn't understand as per [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and requires either type assertions or overloads also.  Unless you want to see that written up I think I'll bow out because the existing answer is probably the best approach.

Comment: @jcalz no worries, and thank you for the help! I'll use overloads then. I didn't realize this, it's weird to have subtypes to `string`, I've never seen that in any other language. Feels like a flaw in Typescript, there should be a way to specify type "exactly string, no less, no more". But I guess that would result in problems in other situations or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve is to use function overload:

```ts
// call signatures
function listToList(listItem: undefined, startList: string[], endList: string[]): undefined
function listToList(listItem: string, startList: string[], endList: string[]): string 

// implementation
function listToList(listItem: string | undefined, startList: string[], endList: string[]): string | undefined {
  if (listItem === undefined) {
    return listItem; 
  }
  const index = startList.indexOf(listItem); 
  if (index === -1) {
    throw `Item not in list!`;
  }
  return endList[index]; 
}

const v1 = listToList(undefined, ['a'], ['b'])
const v2 = listToList('a', ['a'], ['b'])
```

See [Type "is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'RGT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783310/type-is-assignable-to-the-constraint-of-type-t-but-t-could-be-instantiated)

Comment: This worked after I changed the first overload definition to have `string | undefined` (because that's what I'm sometimes sending in, never `undefined` on purpose of course). But this feels like a hacky way of doing it, since I'm not having several fundamentally different function definitions (like you could have in C++ or Java). Also, sending in `undefined` spits out `string | undefined`, which is not a problem for me, but is technically wrong. This feels like exactly the kind of situation generics were created for, and I don't understand why it doesn't work?